# Runtime add algorithm to a program

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, plugins

I'm creating a program that make some matrix analysis. Now i want to implement some basic algorithms but I need to allow users implement new algorithms in the future without recompile the code.
I suppose that these algorithms already exist, probably in c/c++ language.

How can I do it if I use qt? 
Maybe it's better use an other programming language and why?

Comment: You can use the Qt plugins mecanism.

Comment: Maybe hook in some external scripting language? See e.g. [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/index.html), or [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).

Comment: Please explain how they can "implement new algorithms" if "these algorithms already exist", there's a pretty big difference.

Comment: I can vouch for the use of boost python, it's an excellent library and will allow you to do what you are after.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a little. You say that the users have no programming knowledge but you still want them to make small code snippets in C or C++? Or are you going to provide them with the code, and they just paste it into your program? If the latter, then the answer by parrowdice will do fine as then ***you*** make the DLLs and just give them to the users to copy to the correct path.

Comment: Or you can have the algorithms already built into the program, and just provide a list for the users to select.

Comment: On top of supporting plugins Qt also has ECMAScript scripting. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtscript.html#details

Comment: ok, I already have a list of algorithms implemented inside, but I in the web you can find a lot of algorithm in c/c++....user copy the code that in the web, and paste it into my program...this is the "original" idea..there are a lot of problems as you know, first c++/qt is a good language to develop this program?! Maybe phyton it's better, but the conseguence is that I'll have problem to do Unit Test ecc..so I prefer use c++/qt..better for performance and tests,if I use c++,how can i do? Do i have to integrte a phyton module to I have to integrate a module in python to interpret the c++ code?

Comment: BTW the Qt scripting can use Qt code that you have written in c++. I think c++/Qt good for this.

Comment: And finally: ***Never*** trust the user. The users will make mistakes or do something malicious, so never run their code outside of a sandbox and always validate input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suppose that these algorithms already exist, probably in c/c++ language

If that's so, one way would be to write your program capable of loading [DLLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library), and then your users can compile their own algorithm DLL plugins for your application.

Or if you don't expect your users to be able to compile the existing c/c++ algorithms, maybe you can do as Joachim Pileborg suggests, and add in a scripting interface.

Comment: thank you for your suggest, but users don't have to compile anything...thay don't have a compiler and programming knowledgement, thay just have algorithms write in c/c++ and have to insert it into my progam

Comment: Sorry to say but that's not possible. If they have c/c++ code, it will need to be compiled. You will either need to build and supply the plugins yourself, or provide some sort of scripting interface (if the user is not to compile anything).

Comment: There is some C/C++ embedded interpreter like Ch. But, using another language like Python would be a better idea...